# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of Linear Operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the eigenvalues of $T$ and an ordered basis $B$ such that $[T]_B$ is a diagonal matrix. 
$$
T(a,b)=(-2a+3b, -10a+9b).
$$
I know how to find eigenvalues of matrices, but the linear operator tripped me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bf{\text{Ideas required:}}$

Your first observation should be that $T$ corresponds to the matrix 
$A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}-2  & 3\\
                       -10 & 9\end{array}\right]$, as

$T\left[\begin{array}{c}a\\b\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc}-2  & 3\\
                       -10 & 9\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}a\\b\end{array}\right]$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

This matrix $A$ is also denoted by $[T]_{E}$ where $E = \left\{\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right]\right\}$ is the standard ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

For any basis $B$, you can calculate $[T]_{B}$ by evaluating $T$ at each element of $B$ and taking the results to be the columns of $[T]_{B}$.  For example, the first column of $A$ is simply $T\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right]$.

For any basis $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, we have unique invertible transition matrices $P_{E\leftarrow B}$ and $P_{B\leftarrow E}$ which satisfy $[T]_{B} = P_{B\leftarrow E}[T]_{E}P_{E\leftarrow B}$ and $P_{B\leftarrow E}^{-1} = P_{E\leftarrow B}$.

For this problem it is important to note that any invertible matrix $P$ may be considered a transition matrix from coordinates in $E$ to coordinates in some other basis.

---

$\bf{\text{How to solve your problem:}}$

You can use the standard diagonalization process to find an invertible $P$ and diagonal matrix $D$ such that $D = P^{1}[T]_{E}P$.

From here you can insist that $D = [T]_{B}$ for some ordered basis $B = \{\beta_{1},\beta_{2}\}$, and that $P = P_{E\leftarrow B}$.

Finally, compute the basis elements in $B$ by setting $\beta_1 = P^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right], \beta_2 = P^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right]$

Comment: It would depend on the domain and target space of $T$.  Most importantly, are the restrictions on $f(x)$ given in this context?  Like, is it a polynomial of degree $n$ or less, for example?

Comment: Hint:  You can write every such polynomial in the form $a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3$.  What is a natural basis for $P_{3}(R)$?

Comment: (1,x,x^2,x^3) I'm mostly confused how the differentials come into play

Comment: If $f(x) = a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3$, then what is $f'(x)$?

Comment: Here's a good place to start.  Let $B = \{1, x, x^{2}, x^{3}\}$ be an ordered basis for $P_{3}(R)$.  Let $T:P_{3}(R)\to P_{3}(R)$ be the derivative operator.  That is, let $T(f(x)) = f'(x)$.  Then what is $[T]_{B}$.  This is the first question you should answer.

Comment: so I moved forward and ended up with x*f'(x) being represented by the column (0,1,2,3) f''(x) being (2,6,0,0) and -f(2) being (-2,0,0,0) but this makes a 4x3

Comment: Can you please give a precite formulation of the problem and summarize your work in a new question?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the matrix you're looking for is:

$A=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
-2 & 3\\
-10 & 9\\
 \end{array} \right).$

Since you can think of your linear operator as left multiplication by a matrix on the vector:

$v=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a\\
b\\
 \end{array} \right).$

So, $Tv=Av$ where $A$ is above. Now proceed as usual with $A$.